# Im trying to code the recursive fibonacci sequence in c++ but when I compile I get an error

Tags: c++, recursion, fibonacci

When i try to compute the fibonacci sequence using a recursive algorithm in c++, I get an error about memory allocation. I can run a recursive algorithm that has a void return, but when and int is the return, there is an issue with memory. Is there a way around this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fib(int start);

int main()
{
  int x,y;
  cout << "Enter a value for x: ";
  cin >> x;


  y = fib(x);
  cout << "Your product is: ";
  cout << y << endl;
  return 0;

}

int fib(int start){
  if(start == 0 || start == 1){
    return start;
  }
  return fib(start)*fib(start-1);
}
```

Comment: You don't modify `start` when calling `fib(start)`, how is it supposed to reach 1 or 0?

Comment: ***get an error about memory allocation.*** Please post the error message.

Comment: What happens if you call `fib(2)`? It recursively calls `fib(2)`, which recursively calls `fib(2)`, which recursively calls `fib(2)`, which ... is not good for your program's health.

Comment: Recursion for Fibonacci is not `fib(start)*fib(start-1)`, but `fib(start-1) + fib(start-2)`.

Comment: Oh I see. Because of infinite recursion you have a very fitting error for this site..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the fibonacci function is not right...

if your variable `start` happens to be different from 0 or 1 then you can the function fib(start) over and over again

```
return fib(start)*fib(start-1);
```

that will produce an stackoverflow since the function is calling itself infinitely.

on the other hand you should not multiply those values but add it instead

```
 return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `fib()` will not work properly, 
please try this:

```
if(n == 0 || n == 1)
{
return n;
}
else
 return ( fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) );
```

Answer (score 0):

To see what's going on I recommend adding the following to the above answer:
Allowing you to also find the Big O notation
    #include

```
using namespace std;

int fib(int n, int &count) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
    {
        return n;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "n: " << n << endl;
        count += 1;
        return (fib(n - 1, count) + fib(n - 2, count));
    }
}

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    cout << fib(9, count) << endl;
    cout << "Parses Count : " << count << endl;
    cin.get();
   cin.ignore();
}
```